# Jquery asp.net wcf server answer format

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf

i am going under and try to understand how jquery works with asp.net. If i want to use my own class in response in wcf service function i cant get answer from it... So, what i am doing

Wcf service:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class Service2
    {
        [DataContract]
        public class Message
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string MessageBody
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
             [DataMember]
            public string Sender
            {

                get;
                set;

            }

        }

        static List<Message> list = new List<Message>();


        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public List<Message> newone(string a, string b)
        {
            list.Add(new Message {MessageBody = a, Sender= b});
            return list;
        }

    }
```

And try to get answer from this function from jquery

```
 function hi() {

                $.ajax({
                    async: true,
                    url: '/Service2.svc/newone',
                    data: 'a= ' + $('#my1').val() + '&b= ' + $('#my2').val(),
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        var str = '';
                        str += data.MessageBody[0];//To take first message from list


                        $("#msgs").html(str);



                    },
                    error: function() {alert('error');}

                });

            }
```

It doesnot work... What i must do to get MessageBody and Sender from server? How i can get first element in list second and so on? Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

So, i dont get an answer on my question and find it by myself... so it is not very complicate we must just do this - data.d[i].MessageBody if want to take message from list.